# Tell View which area to draw

Tags: android, view, canvas, drawing

My question may be a bit unclear, but I have extended the View class and generated a number of shapes on the canvas around `(0,0)`. I want to put this point in the middle, so I have to tell the View that it has to draw horizontally, for example, from `-640` to `640` on the x-axis and vertically, for example, from `-360` to `360` on the y-axis.

Is there a way to tell the view that it has to draw these pixels without changing the coordinates of the drawn shapes. I just want to tell the view that it has to draw certain coordinates.

I want to be able to change dynamically which area is drawn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% what you are trying to achieve, but *if you want to move and scale* your shapes, you can use the canvas [translate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#translate%28float,%20float%29) or [scale](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#scale%28float,%20float%29) methods, to move the canvas to under your shapes. Remember that it is the canvas you translate, and not the shape, so the transformations will have to be done in reverse. You should also use the canvas [save](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#save%28int%29) and [restore](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#restore%28%29) methods to restore your canvas position between transformations.

*If you instead want to limit any drawing to an area*, you can use the canvas [clip-methods](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#clipRect%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29), for example:

```
canvas.clipRect(-640, -360, 640, 360);
```

Would case any drawing outside that rectangle to be discarded.

Comment: The translate method did the trick, thank you very much. My infinitely large scrollable canvas works :D